# Need to insert a worksheet into the body of an email but NOT send it

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet ("WC Referral Notice") that I need to put into the body of an email, but NOT send it immediately since I need to browse and attach several documents to the email before it is sent. I found macros to send it in the body of the email but it's sent as soon as you click. And I've also found macros to attach the workbook as an attachment. Neither of those are exactly what I'm looking for.

```
    Sub Send_Selection_Or_ActiveSheet_with_MailEnvelope()
Dim Sendrng As Range

On Error GoTo StopMacro

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Set Sendrng = Selection

With Sendrng

    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
    With .Parent.MailEnvelope

        .Introduction = " "

        With .Item
            .To = "adicker@generic.com"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "WC Referral Notice"
            .Send
        End With

    End With
End With

StopMacro:
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried, so you don't get duplicate suggestions. Also, most VBA code to create/send e-mails has a line with `.Send` somewhere. That line is what causes the e-mail to actually send.

Comment: It does have .Send. I've tried to change it to .Display which I thought would do it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: So please add the code you've tried.....

Comment: It's in the box underneath the question

Comment: Read this thread....It says to add .item in front of .Send Still doesnt work :(   https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/692050-how-display-email-before-sending-using-mailenvelope.html

Comment: figured it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
    Sub Send_Range_Or_Whole_Worksheet_with_MailEnvelope()

Dim AWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim Sendrng As Range
Dim rng As Range

On Error GoTo StopMacro

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

'Fill in the Worksheet/range you want to mail
'Note: if you use one cell it will send the whole worksheet
Set Sendrng = Worksheets("WC Referral Notice").Range("A1:H101")

'Remember the activesheet
Set AWorksheet = ActiveSheet

With Sendrng

    ' Select the worksheet with the range you want to send
    .Parent.Select

    'Remember the ActiveCell on that worksheet
    Set rng = ActiveCell

    'Select the range you want to mail
    .Select

    ' Create the mail and send it
    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
    With .Parent.MailEnvelope

        ' Set the optional introduction field thats adds
        ' some header text to the email body.
        .Introduction = "This is test mail 2."

        With .Item
            .To = "adicker@generic.com"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "Blah Blah"
            .Item.Send
        End With

    End With

    'select the original ActiveCell
    rng.Select
End With

'Activate the sheet that was active before you run the macro
AWorksheet.Select
StopMacro:
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
'ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = False

End Sub
```